# is it possible to release the GIL before a C function that blocks and might call back into Python?

Tags: python, gil, python-multithreading, python-bindings

I am wrapping a C function which performs a blocking operation (select) and then handles incoming messages.  My understanding is that when a C function is going to block, the correct way to call it while allowing other threads to run is:

```
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS                                                  
blocking_function();
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

However, it happens that this function takes as a parameter a callback pointer.  This callback is called on handling the incoming message that is pre-processed by the C function.  I have successfully wrapped this callback in a function which calls `PyEval_CallObject()`, allowing me to pass it a Python callback.

Now that I'm adding threading support, I'm wondering if it's possible to simultaneously:

- Release the GIL before calling this blocking operation.
- Have this blocking operation safely call back into the python interpreter.

Is this going to cause problems?  If so, is there a way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the right approach might be to re-capture the GIL in my handler that calls `PyEval_CallObject`.  However, this means passing forward the saved `PyThreadState`, which seems a bit tricky!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used these API functions several months ago, and my recollection is a bit hazy, but I believe this code will solve your problem.  I am assuming version 2.x (3.x may be different):

```
PyGILState_STATE gstate;
gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

/* Make your call to PyEval_CallObject() here (and any other PY API calls). */

PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

(The above was taken from: [Python C/API docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock))

This is basically the inverse of the Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS/Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
 macros.  Within those, you release the GIL, but within the PyGILState functions you acquire the GIL.

Comment: The PyGILState_Ensure/Release API is valid for Python 3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Works if I use a global to store the result of `PyEval_SaveThread`, and use this in the callback to call `PyEval_RestoreThread`.  I just need to figure out how to more cleanly pass this to the callback in my code through the callback's context pointer.

Comment: Now that the PyGILState APIs are available, it is a *much* better idea to use those (as described in dappawit's answer).